# How to print the digit in the second decimal place for the numbers in column 2. UNIX

Tags: unix, awk

Okay, so im new to Unix and I am trying to learn the basics of Unix. I have a file called adafile that im trying to configure and just toy around with. I basically want to print the digits in the second decimal place for the numbers in column 2 (which is 1,3,5,6,4,6,2,4).

```
File Output:
3.0 .91 7 36 January JAN Wayne Smith
2.8 .83 4 17 February FEB Eric Kittle
5.1 .95 8 15 March MAR Morgan Leach
9.0 .76 7 19 April APR Jane Holder
3.5 .84 4 43 October OCT Victor Carter
5.2 .98 6 13 November NOV Michael John
4.5 .86 2 8 December DEC Harry Kaka
5.7 .96 4 13 September SEP Tim Simple
```

How do I go about getting this done without the use of scripts? I tried using the command: nawk '{print $2}' adafile

```
Output:
.91
.83
.95
.76
.84
.98
.86
.96
```

- but I know it would show all the content in the 2nd column.

Should I be using the nawk command or is there a better command for this?

If I could get any help I much appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried code/efforts in your question, thank you.

Comment: `awk '{print substr($2, 3, 1)}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE 1*** : adding a purely `regex` approach :

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='^.+[.].| .+$' OFS=
> ```

-- this also works, but with side-effect of extra space to the left

> ```
> mawk NF=2 FS='^.+[.].| .+$'
> ```

```
[ ] 1
    3
    5
    6
    4
    8
    6
    6
```

——————————————————

> ```
> gawk '$_ = substr($(_+=++_),_+--_,_--)'
> nawk '$-__= substr($(_=NF),    _,!__)' FS='^.*[.]'
> mawk '$!NF = substr($(_=NF),  _,!__)'  FS='^.*[.]'
> ```

```
1
3
5
6
4
8
6
6
```

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
File Output:
3.0 .91 7 36 January JAN Wayne Smith
2.8 .83 4 17 February FEB Eric Kittle
5.1 .95 8 15 March MAR Morgan Leach
9.0 .76 7 19 April APR Jane Holder
3.5 .84 4 43 October OCT Victor Carter
5.2 .98 6 13 November NOV Michael John
4.5 .86 2 8 December DEC Harry Kaka
5.7 .96 4 13 September SEP Tim Simple
```

then

```
awk 'NR>1{print $2*100%10}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1
3
5
6
4
8
6
6
```

Explanation: for lines beyond 1st (`NR>1`) multiply 2nd field value by `100` then take remainder of division (`%`) by `10`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: `File Output:` from the question is not part of the input file so the `NR>1` should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a script would I guess be:

```
$ cut -c7 file
1
3
5
6
4
8
6
6
```

to get the posted expected output from your posted sample input but YMMV for other values so if I were you I would use a script, e.g.:

```
$ awk '{print ( match($2,/\./) ? substr($2,RSTART+2,1)+0 : 0 )}' file
1
3
5
6
4
8
6
6
```

That will produce numeric output even if the value in $0 doesn't have a decimal point or does but only has 1 digit after it instead of the 2 in your example, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
3.0    .91  7 36 January JAN Wayne Smith
2.8    .8   4 17 February FEB Eric Kittle
5.7   2     4 13 September SEP Tim Simple
```

```
$ awk '{print ( match($2,/\./) ? substr($2,RSTART+2,1)+0 : 0 )}' file
1
0
0
```